# Excel how to make one sum formula for entire colum which sums each row separately?

Tags: excel, sum

I am completely new to excel, so I'd like to apologize in advance if this question seems silly. I do have a solid programming / logic background.

Situation:
Column B contains the sum of each row in this fashion

```
(=SUM(Cn:Ln)) where n is the row number.
```

I now have each field in column B filled with a formula (where n is the row number).

What I want:
One formula for column B that has the same result as described. Something like

```
=SUM(Cn:Ln)
```

Hope someone can help me out here!

Kevin

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.  `SUM()` should work for formulas as well as numbers?

Comment: Normally you just enter the required formula in the first row and drag or fill down, row numbers will change automatically, e.g. if you have this formula in B2 - =SUM(C2:L2) then when you drag it down the row numbers will change

Comment: As I said, I'm new to excel. Didn't even know what the drag option did...untill now. Thnx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excel range references can be absolute or relative. Relative references move as you copy the formula (or move or fill).  So, in A1, this formula

```
=SUM(B1:L1)
```

when copied to A2 becomes

```
=SUM(B2:L2)
```

You copied the formula one row down, so the range references (being relative) refer to the range one row down from the original.  The same is true for columns. Had you copied that formula to B2

```
=SUM(C2:M2)
```

The dollar sign makes a reference absolute. An absolute reference does not change when the formula is copied. You can make the row absolute, the column absolute, or both.  Copy the formula on the left from A1 to D10 to get the formula on the right

```
=$B$2   =$B$2    both row and column absolute, no change
=B2     =E11     both row and column relative, both change
=$B2    =$B11    column absolute, only the row changes
=B$2    =E$2     row absolute, only the column changes
```

Answer (score 0):

try
=SUM(C$n:L$N)
where n is your first row and N is your Last row

so if you had a table such as

```
      A          B        C     D  >>>   L
1     Bob       Tom       1     1        1
2     sue       Mary      1     1        1 
3     no         yes      1     1        1
4
5    Sum                                 9
```

of course, you could define a range in Excel too.